# installing packages on Python

Tags: python, matrix, installation, package

This is my first evening playing with Python and it turns into a horror show. I am trying to install num package. Within idle I am trying to do 
pip3 num.py install ( as in instructions) and I am getting invalid syntax 
I also tried 
"python num.py install" with the same result. 
My initial impression of the language is grave disappointment. For example Idle is primitive compared to the R-Studio development environment in R. 
can somebody help in this forum? 
Thanks!

Comment: It's probably best to use virtual environments to manage Python installations and packages (I use Conda, for example). _Within idle I am trying to do pip3 num.py install_ `pip` should be used from the command line, it isn't Python code. _For example Idle is primitive compared to the R-Studio development environment in R._ No need to worry, there are plenty of different IDEs/editors that you can use!

Comment: _and I am getting invalid syntax I also tried "python num.py install" with the same result._ Please share the entire error message.